# Delphi 10.2 Tokyo - Casting object provided by interface

Tags: delphi, interface, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to convert my aplliction from Delphi XE8 to 10.2 Tokyo. I'm getting strange runtime exeptions with casting objects provided by interfafce acrocss packages ( bpl's). when I try to cast objects with "as" keyword I'm getting 
this exception during runtime:

> Project Project1.exe raised exception class EInvalidCast with message
>   'Invalid class typecast'

Here is the code :

Interface in a separte package Plugin_interface.bpl :

```
unit MainIntf;

interface
  Type IMainInft = interface
  ['{FE08C4A2-069C-4B8C-BB1B-445348CAB6A0}']
    function GetForm : TObject;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

Interface implamentation provided in Project1.exe :

```
unit MainImpl;

interface
uses MainIntf;

  Type TMain = class(TInterfacedObject,IInterface,IMainInft)
    function GetForm : TObject;
end;


implementation
uses unit1;

function TMain.GetForm: TObject ;
begin
  result:=Form1; // interafce is implemented on the main form so Form1 is rechable form here
end;


end.
```

And finally in another package "plugin.bpl" I'm  trying to obtain object from interface :

```
unit Plugin_main;

interface
uses Mainintf, Vcl.Forms;

type TPlugin = class (Tobject)
  IIMyRefernceToMianIntf: IMainInft;
end;

function RegisterPlugin(AMainIntf: IMainInft): TForm ; export;
procedure UnRegisterPlugin; export;

exports
  RegisterPlugin,
  UnRegisterPlugin;

var
 Plugin_obj:  TPlugin;

implementation
uses vcl.Dialogs,System.Classes ;

function RegisterPlugin(AMainIntf: IMainInft): TForm ;
var
 MyForm : TForm ;
begin
  Plugin_obj:=TPlugin.Create;
  Plugin_obj.IIMyRefernceToMianIntf:=AMainIntf;

  if AMainIntf.GetForm is TForm then
    Showmessage ('Great it is a Tform') // will not happen
  else
    Showmessage ('Sorry  it is not Tform'); // will happen 
  if TComponent (AMainIntf.GetForm).Classname='TForm1' then
    Showmessage ('What ?? It is TForm1 decsendant from TForm  so is it TForm after all ?!');  // will happen 
// result:=  AMainIntf.GetForm as TForm  -- This will rise na exception
  result:= TForm( AMainIntf.GetForm)  ; // this will work

end;

procedure UnRegisterPlugin;
begin
  Plugin_obj.Free;
end;
end.
```

Why cant I use "as" and "is" keyword . 
Only hard catsing will do, but i hate to do it .
on XE8 compiler everything worked as expected - problem exists on XE 10.2 tokyo compiler

Comment: Are your projects compiled with runtime packages enabled? This kind of error usually means a single instance of the RTL/VCL libraries is not being shared across the executables, causing RTTI to be different in each executable.

Comment: Thanks Remy - that's it - this option has moved in XE10.2 and is now called "Link with runtime packages" on a separte option page called " Runtime Packages"

Comment: @jackDph: there is no XE 10.2. It is Delphi or RAD Studio 10.2, no XE in sight. The XE line stopped at XE8.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, you should really make this into an answer, or -better- find the duplicate and close it.

Answer (score -1):

The "is" keyword checks the actual objects to see it is of the type you are asking. So, checking for this:

```
if AMainIntf.GetForm is TForm then
Showmessage ('Great it is a Tform') // will not happen
```

does not happen because `GetForm` returns `TObject` and not `TForm`. Checking with "is" means, also, that you are checking for castability, i.e. the ability to use the "as" keyword. Since, the "is" check fails, that command fails as well:

```
result:=  AMainIntf.GetForm as TForm;
```

Your next option here is to hard-cast GetForm the way you do it:

```
TForm(AMainIntf.GetForm);
```

which works because this casting does not check whether `GetForm` is of `TForm` type. Since you return a form in `TMain`, this hard-casting is safe bet for you.

Having said that, however, why don't you return `TForm` directly rather than `TObject`? Do you use `IMainInft` in other classes that return other types than `TForm`?

Comment: The `as` operator will work as long as the object on the left has `TForm` somewhere in it's class hierarchy. The problem here (as Remy states in their comment above) is that the BPL was not sharing the type data with the executable so had a different `TForm`.